# Errors with Grails application session data on Amazon Cloud Web Services

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, grails-2.0

I have a Grails 2.0.0 web application that runs in both a DEV and a PROD environment without any problems. Both environments are on a CentOS 6.0 server running Tomcat 7.

Due to customer requirements, I have been tasked with deploying the application to the cloud with Amazon's Web Services. I have been able to do this, however I am seeing strange behavior with any form fields (i.e. dropdown boxes) that read/write session data. For example, when I choose a value from a dropdown box, the chosen value should be saved to the session and recalled after an ajax call to filter a corresponding list of country data. If I choose "Bermuda", the dropdown value actually (incorrectly) changes to another country from the list (after the ajax call), that I did not select.

While I have confirmed that the session variable contains the wrong country, I have also confirmed that all of the application specific code is working correctly (as it should, since it does so on the DEV and PROD environments). I believe that the problem may be a result of having different environment configurations. My DEV/PROD environments use CentOS 6.0, but my Amazon Cloud environment uses Red Hat Linux.  Since Amazon does not provide a CentOS image, Red Hat was the closest flavor that I could find.

I'm wondering if the difference in configurations could be impacting the functionality. Or, maybe it is something specific to Amazon. For example, all incoming/outgoing traffic passes through Amazon's internal Threat Management Gateway (TMG). Perhaps this is affecting the session data?

Has anyone had any similar experiences? Or can anyone point me in the right direction? This problem has been affecting me for weeks now...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Microsoft TMG was set to perform caching, which caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The RedHad, CentOS and Amazon Linux have mostly the same packages, except for some additional packages that would probably not interfere in the running.

I think Amazon internal TMG isn't also the problem, because it would block the network packets but it wouldn't change the packet content.

Then it lasts only tomcat, grails and your application:

1. have you tried to upgrade grails version to 2.0.4 or 2.1.0?
2. did you confirm in your logs that your ajax request is actually being processed?
3. what is your Xms, Xmx and PermGen tomcat configurations?
4. what is the size of your EC2 VM? if it is m1.micro you should change to m1.small?

Also I would advise you to try other Amazon product called [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-freetier/deploy-sample-app.html), which uses EC2, Auto Scaling Group, Elastic Load Balance and Cloud Watch, offering a very simplified and integrated console to manage your environment, making it very quick to test different configurations.

If today you have MySQL installed you might want to replace it with a MySQL RDS instance and leave your EC2 instances just for Web Application.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I've been considering all of your suggestions. It seems that the issue is not occurring when tested out from a Windows machine that is within the TMG. Unfortunately, we don't have access to that machine (yet), but another team is looking into it. I will surely update the thread once I hear more. Thanks for your help!